# problems with react-webcam

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webcam

I have a problem with react-webcam which is when I open my page immediately it asks me for permission to open my camera, but what I need is to ask for my permission only if I press the button to take a picture

```
const WebcamCapture = () => {
  const webcamRef = React.useRef(null)
  const [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = React.useState(null)

  const capture = React.useCallback(() => {
    const imageSrc = webcamRef.current.getScreenshot()
    setImgSrc(imageSrc)
  }, [webcamRef, setImgSrc])

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="w-full bg-dark-20 flex justify-center items-center relative ">
        <AiOutlineCamera className="text-6xl py-60 h-auto absolute m-auto" />
        <Webcam
          className="w-full h-64"
          audio={false}
          ref={webcamRef}
          screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="flex justify-end mt-5">
        <button
          className="text-xs flex justify-center items-center px-4 py-2 border-2  border-dark-80 rounded"
          onClick={capture}>
          Usar Camara web <BiWebcam className="ml-2 text-base" />
        </button>
      </div>
      {imgSrc && <img src={imgSrc} />}
    </div>
  )
}
export default WebcamCapture
```

Answer (score 1):

In your app, the `Webcam` component is loaded when `WebcamCapture` mounts.  When `Webcam` loads, it will ask for perimission.  If you want to *not* load the `Webcam` component until the user presses the button, you need to conditionally render the `Webcam` based on a state variable that is controlled with a button.  For example, have a button that once pressed, renders the webcam and the button to take a photo:

```js
const WebcamCapture = () => {
  const webcamRef = React.useRef(null)
  const [camOpen, setCamOpen] = React.useState(false)
  const [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = React.useState(null)


  const capture = React.useCallback(() => {
    if (webcamRef){
      const imageSrc = webcamRef.current.getScreenshot()
      setImgSrc(imageSrc)
    }
  }, [webcamRef, setImgSrc, webcamRef])

  return (
    <div>

      {camOpen && 
        <>
          <div className="...">
            <Webcam/>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-end mt-5">
            <button
              className="..."
              onClick={capture}>
                Usar Camara web <BiWebcam className="ml-2 text-base" />
            </button>
          </div>
        </>
      }

      <button onClick={capture}>Open the camera</button>

      {imgSrc && <img src={imgSrc} />}

    </div>
  )
}
export default WebcamCapture
```

But you can't have the `Webcam` already being in use, then only ask for permission to use it once the user wants to take a photo.  You can create a custom modal that says something like "Are you sure you want to take a photo?" once the user clicks the button to capture a photo, but in order for the webcam to render, it needs permission first.

Comment: I get this error Cannot read property 'getScreenshot' of null :( , https://codesandbox.io/s/we-cam-react-05w12?file=/src/webcam.js

Comment: That makes sense...you are trying to refer to the `ref` of the `Webcam` and use a method from it, when it has not yet been rendered.  You will probably want to move the contents of the `{camOpen && ... }` statement into its own component, along with your callback function.  My answer was focused on explaining the flow of component renderings and where giving permission to the camera fits in.

Comment: Or the quick and dirty way to fix that error is to make your callback have the `webcamRef` variable as a dependency, and only attempt to grab the ref if it exists